# Message block not works in checkout onepage

Tags: onepage-checkout, messages

I have form and button coupon code in onepage checkout
But when i apply coupon code, it always redirect to `checkout/cart`.
-I want to redirect page to checkout/onepage after apply coupon code
-I try change function `_goBack()` in `CartController()` like this :

```
protected function _goBack()
{
$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');
return $this;
}
```

It works but doesn't show message block if correct or fail code, if i go any another page, it display this message.
I try add `getMessagesBlock()->toHtml()` ?> to template but it don't show 
Pls help me

Comment: where you added the message???

Comment: i added it to template checkout/onepage.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Add this message code on your function

```
$message = 'Error Message';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
Show Success message in frontend

$message = 'Success Message';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);
```

This will prepare your message and show it on frontend when you will redirect to any page.

**Hope this will help you! Happy learning**

Answer (score 0):

Following explanations for Magento ver. 1.9.1.0:

In the `couponPostAction()` of the `CartController.php` the messages are added to the `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` as you can see `$this->_getSession()->addSuccess(...`. This is the reason for which when the `indexAction()` of the `CartController.php` is called you can see: 
`$this->loadLayout()
      ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
      ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session')` so the messages are rendered in the cart page. 
 
In the checkout template (`checkout/onepage.phtml`), even if you put
`getMessagesBlock()->toHtml()` (or `echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()` for my version of Magento) the block message is not displayed because the `checkout/session` messages are not initialized in the `indexAction()` of the `OnepageController.php`. Here, only the 
`$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');` is called. 
 
**Solution:** you should also initialize checkout/session layout messages when the onepage checkout is being called.